# Best What's new book about just changes and new features in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to read about new changes and new features in SQL Server 2012.I found some E-Book in the internet but they have basic topics (like create Tables,Views,...) I want a book that just cover new features.Is there any book?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always read the [what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15) sections in the BOL. As for a book, have you looked at Microsoft's free [book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/free-ebook-introducing-microsoft-sql-server-2012)? A hard copy is available too, if you prefer. The book is not a coursebook but more general an approach. As per introduction:

> **Who Should Not Read This Book**
>
> As mentioned earlier, the purpose of this book is to provide the
> reader with a high-level preview of the capabilities and features
> associated with SQL Server 2012. This book is not intended to be a
> step- by-step comprehensive guide.

Comment: Books online is enough. I seriously wonder why people go around asking for books and third party stuff and never bother to start with the obvious - the documentation.